# I wanna deploy my Node.js app on firebase using MongoDB database. But I'm getting just firebase welcome page, not my website

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, web-deployment, firebase-hosting

My project showing me "deployed successfully" on firebase. But when I clicked that link its just showing firebase welcome page and not my project. Image link is here:

[image]

here is app.js file:

```
//jshint esversion:6

    const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const express = require("express");
    const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
    const ejs = require("ejs");
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
    const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
    const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";
    const profileContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    
    mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://admin-username:<password>@cluster0.quojn.mongodb.net/blogDB", {useNewUrlParser: true});
    
    const postSchema = {
      title: String,
      content: String
    };
    
    const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
    
    app.get("/", function(req, res){
    
      Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
        res.render("home", {
          startingContent: homeStartingContent,
          posts: posts
          });
      });
    });
    
    app.get("/profile",function(req,res){
      
      Post.find({}, function(err, posts){
        res.render("profile", {
        profileContent:profileContent,
        posts: posts
        });
      });
    });
    
    app.post("/delete",function(req,res){
      const deletedpostID = req.body.delbutton;
    
      Post.findByIdAndRemove(deletedpostID,function(err){
        if(!err){
          console.log("success");
        }
        res.redirect("/");
      });
    })
    
    app.get("/compose", function(req, res){
      res.render("compose");
    });
    
    app.post("/compose", function(req, res){
      const post = new Post({
        title: req.body.postTitle,
        content: req.body.postBody
      });
    
    
      post.save(function(err){
        if (!err){
            res.redirect("/");
        }
      });
    });

app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res){

const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;

  Post.findOne({_id: requestedPostId}, function(err, post){
    res.render("post", {
      title: post.title,
      content: post.content
    });
  });
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about", {aboutContent: aboutContent});
});

app.get("/contact", function(req, res){
  res.render("contact", {contactContent: contactContent});
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

firebase.json file:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ],
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  }
}
```

I also have tried to deploy using firebase functions but showing me a lots of error in cmd terminal:

```
=== Deploying to 'blogsite-project-e6563'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> eslint .


C:\Users\HP\Documents\Blogsite-project\functions\index.js
   6:7   error  'ejs' is assigned a value but never used              no-unused-vars
   9:1   error  This line has a length of 703. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
  10:1   error  This line has a length of 564. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
  11:1   error  This line has a length of 670. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
  12:1   error  This line has a length of 670. Maximum allowed is 80  max-len
  25:18  error  Missing trailing comma                                comma-dangle
  30:32  error  Block must not be padded by blank lines               padded-blocks
  30:32  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  32:37  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  35:19  error  Missing trailing comma                                comma-dangle
  36:1   error  Expected indentation of 4 spaces but found 6          indent
  40:19  error  A space is required after ','                         comma-spacing
  40:32  error  A space is required after ','                         comma-spacing
  40:37  error  Block must not be padded by blank lines               padded-blocks
  40:37  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  41:1   error  Trailing spaces not allowed                           no-trailing-spaces
  42:37  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  44:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 4          indent
  44:20  error  Missing space before value for key 'profileContent'   key-spacing
  45:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 4          indent
  45:17  error  Missing trailing comma                                comma-dangle
  50:20  error  A space is required after ','                         comma-spacing
  50:33  error  A space is required after ','                         comma-spacing
  50:38  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  51:43  error  Missing semicolon                                     semi
  53:40  error  There should be no space before ','                   comma-spacing
  53:55  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  54:5   error  Expected space(s) after "if"                          keyword-spacing
  54:13  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  59:3   error  Missing semicolon                                     semi
  61:39  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  65:40  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  68:31  error  Missing trailing comma                                comma-dangle
  72:26  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  73:14  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  74:1   error  Expected indentation of 6 spaces but found 8          indent
  79:45  error  Block must not be padded by blank lines               padded-blocks
  79:45  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  81:1   error  Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 0          indent
  83:59  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  86:28  error  Missing trailing comma                                comma-dangle
  91:37  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks
  95:39  error  Missing space before opening brace                    space-before-blocks

✖ 43 problems (43 errors, 0 warnings)
  38 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.

events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)   
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\node_modules\cross-env\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:30:37)   
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12) {
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  path: 'npm --prefix "%RESOURCE_DIR%" run lint',
  spawnargs: []
}

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

I've searched on internet why this is happening. Please help to resolve this errors. Will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the end of the logs.

> Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code 1

The code is not deploying because of eslint errors. Resolve those and try deploying again.